# How can I count the number of components on a page that have been connected with redux' connect() function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm doing some performance analysis on a large React/Redux app that uses many connected components (hundreds).

I'd like to keep track of the number of connected components as a performance metric so that I can accurately estimate my per-frame budget for e.g. `mapStateToProps` and other Redux logic.

React devtools has access to all of the components on a page, so I'm looking to either reuse the same hook it does or would also accept any hook that allows me to enumerate all components on a page (and from there I can figure out if they're wrapped in `Connect` or not).

Comment: one potential lead: https://github.com/bruderstein/react-render-hook

Comment: This is definitely possible with React devtool hooks, but the problem is that Redux connected components don't identify themselves unambiguously, and `Connect` component class isn't exposed to check with `instanceof Connect`. react-render-hook doesn't have functionality to spy on connected components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-redux` doesn't seem to have specific functionality to hook into connected components, while Redux dev tools are applied to a store as a middleware and are agnostic of connected React components.

A straightforward way is to monkey-patch `react-redux` module and extend connected component with specific behaviour, a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m9oqrv1orp):

```
import * as reactRedux from "react-redux";

let connectedCount = 0;

function patchConnect(connect) {
  return (...args) => {
    const wrapWithConnect = connect(...args);
    return WrappedComponent => {
      const Connect = wrapWithConnect(WrappedComponent);

      return class ConnectWithCounter extends Connect {
        componentDidMount() {
          console.log(++connectedCount, this);
          super.componentDidMount();
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
          console.log(--connectedCount);
          super.componentWillUnmount();
        }
      };
    };
  };
}

reactRedux.connect = patchConnect(reactRedux.connect);
reactRedux.connectAdvanced = patchConnect(reactRedux.connectAdvanced);

// import the rest of the app that imports redux-react
import('./app').catch(console.error);
```

`react-redux` should be patched first, and modules should be writable. This puts restrictions on modular environment, because ES modules can be read-only (they are, according to the spec) and `import` statements may go before the rest of the code (they should, according to the spec). There's a chance that `reactRedux.connect = ...` patching will happen too late or won't happen at all.

For instance, the example uses Codesandbox which would hoist `import './app'` without an error, and the same example wouldn't work in Stackblitz because SystemJS module implementation results in read-only imports.

It's preferable to configure development environment to use CommonJS modules because `require` allows this kind of modifications.

Comment: I believe I can make this work but I'm currently stuck; whether I use import or require I still get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property connect of #<Object> which has only a getter` when setting `reactRedux.connect`; I'm looking at the webpack/babel documentation now to see how I can allow it

Comment: Yes, this is what the answer refers to. Try to disable module transpilation in Babel with https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html#modules and make Webpack handle them, or make Babel to transpile modules to CommonJS. See also this topic, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039

Comment: sadly adding `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` did not work (same error); I'm still investigating

Comment: have since tried rewiremock and inject-loader without success

Comment: This should be handled at transpiler level. Things like inject-loader will do the same thing as shown in the answer. If module implementation doesn't allow that, they won't work. I'd suggest to address this in separate question, this is very specific to your setup, main script in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve could be reduced to just `import * as reactRedux from "react-redux"; reactRedux.connect = () => {}`. I'm not using Babel much now so I'm not sure if I can efficiently help to resolve this part of the problem.

Comment: agreed; your answer is correct, I just need to fix my setup to implement it :)

Comment: @Beau did you ever get this to work? I have the same issue

Comment: @DavidBradshaw no, sadly!

Comment: @DavidBradshaw If your environment doesn't allow to patch third-party modules, you need to switch 'react-redux' with your own wrapper, e.g. './util/react-redux'.

Comment: I manage to run `why-did-you-update` ok. So it should be possible to do this, but when I follow the same patten for `react-redux` I get this error